# SSH key confusion, 2 quick questions

Tags: git, ssh

On computer **A** I created 2 ssh keys, public and private. The public key was added to the SSH keys on [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/) server (git repo)

On computer A, I am able to push, pull, clone etc with issues, however when using computer **B**, I get

```
git push origin dev:dev
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

In my `~/.ssh/` directory I have a `id_rsa.pub -> /Users/my_uid/Dropbox/ssh/id_rsa.pub`, which matches the one set in `Assembla`

What might the problem be here?

Comment: Do you have the private key on computer B?  How are you "using" computer B?  Are you logged in directly, over ssh from computer A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put your private key in the .ssh folder on whatever computer that you want to use to access remote git repo.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Thank you. How does git know what file contains the key?

Comment: @JAM: It will know which one is public and which one is private just from the structure of the file (you can open with a text editor to see). I'm not sure how it determines between different private keys, though.

Comment: Since `git` just uses `ssh` to connect, it will use whichever key `ssh` would use to connect to the remote host. See the `~/.ssh/config` file for details; the `host` block uses the `IdentityFile` directive to specify the private key to use. The `ssh_config(5)` manpage contains full details.